# What should be PHP/MySQL query for the following requirement?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

It is a shopping cart, where user can add product to watchlist. Have a seprate page of User's watchlist where all product apepears that has been added to watchlist by that particular user. `product_images` table is separated from product table since 1 image can have multiple images.

**MySQL Tables**

```
Table "product" :
    pid(pk),name,price, etc...

Table "watchlist" :
    wid(pk),pid(fk),userid(fk)

Table "p_images" :
    image_id(pk),pid(fk),image_name
```

I want to fetch all information from `product` table and only 1st image of that particular product from `p_images` table.
product should be fetch by pid in `watchlist` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it accurate using LEFT JOIN check following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN P_images i ON p.pid = i.pid
GROUP BY i.pid
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from product p
inner join p_images i on p.pid = i.pid
where p.pid = 1
group by p.pid
order by image_id
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine. But if there is no image of that product query does not return any data from product table either.

Is there any way that if no product_image is there it should return only product information ?

can it be done by mysql query?

Comment: @Dynamic_Dude: Instead of `inner join p_images ...` try `left outer join p_images ...`.